# How to place minimum value of one column into a temp column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

For example, two joined tables:

```
ID  Name  Date
1   a     4-1-2010
1   z     3-3-1999
1   c     1-1-2012
2   e     7-9-2005
2   r     5-1-2000
```

And I'd like to query the table into this:

```
ID  Name  Date       MinDate
1   a     4-1-2010   3-3-1999
1   z     3-3-1999   3-3-1999
1   c     1-1-2012   3-3-1999
2   e     7-9-2005   5-1-2000
2   r     5-1-2000   5-1-2000
```

Is this possible?

```
    My query is as following:
    Select *, Min(Date) AS MinDate
    From table1 
    Join table1 on table1.ID = table2.ID
    Group By ID
```

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes, I was struggling trying to edit to format the tables!

Comment: What do you mean "two joined tables"?  If a query generated that data then you should include the query in your question.

Comment: Is the date structure off here? I would expect YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand without your table structure, but you can get the `min` date per group using `window functions` without using `group by`.  Here's an example using `min() over`:

```
select id, name, date, 
    min(date) over (partition by id) mindate
from table1 
    Join table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that works. Perform a subquery (sub) to find all the minimum date values by id. Then join those minimum values to the corresponding ids in the main table (T):

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.date, sub.mindate
FROM T
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id, min(date) AS mindate
FROM T
GROUP BY id) sub
ON T.id = sub.id
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f539db/3